# After changing file extension from js to ts, ionic cannot find module any more

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular, ionic2

I am using ionic to create a mobile app following the link at http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/getting-started/tutorial/.

```
ionic start my-mobileapp sidemenu --v2
```

Then I start my app in a browser as follows.

```
ionic serve
```

All of this worked until I changed my file extensions from `*.js` to `*.ts`.

> Error: Cannot find module './pages/getting-started/getting-started'
>   from '/Users/jwayne/git/my-mobileapp/app'

If I simply toggle/change the file extensions back to `js` then things work.

My question is how does ionic know that code stored in a js file is actually `TypeScript` and **not** `JavaScript` if TypeScript code is stored in a `js` file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be typing that...

```
ionic start my-mobileapp sidemenu --v2 --ts
```

Comment: Thanks. I restarted the process but it was ok since I wasn't deep into the code yet. However, it's strange that TypeScript code would be placed in files with `js` extensions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with Typescript, you should start a project with the **--ts** flag, as suggested above. Then, you should go about changing parts of your code to make them Typescript compliant.

See here for a good short overview of Javascript (ECMA6) VS Typescript:
http://www.joshmorony.com/converting-ecmascript-6-to-typescript-in-ionic-2/

As a side note, if your project is not too complex yet, I highly suggest you follow the guide and move to Typescript.